# Responsive menu is not working when I start private window. Works only when I refresh page. JS error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, magento2

I'm experiencing this error on lalocasanova.com (magento 2.1) where the responsive menu will not work(nothing happens when I click) unless I refresh the page. It seems to be some sort of JS error. Can you guys point me in the right direction? Im still learning the basics so any detailed help on how to fix this error help is highly appreciated!

The theme is Ves Need by the way.

This is when I fist land on the homepage and nothing happens when I click on the top left corner:
[Responsive menu not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytrru.jpg)

This is when I refresh the page and the menu works:

[Responsive menu working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Th8.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @user1204652. I'm on mobile device and the menu it's working just fine. When it fails you can confirm that no Javascript file is missing? You can see the files that were loaded on the page in developer console "Sources" tab

Comment: @dsilva it looks like it happens if you're on mobile and open safari, open a new private window and menu wont work..

Comment: I'm on android, using Chrome. I open a private tab and the menu still works. I have to try on desktop